# Fast multiplication of very large integers

Tags: c#, java, integer, multiplication

How to multiply two very large numbers greater than 32 characters for example multiplication of 100! with 122! or 22^122 with 11^200  by the help of divide and conquer, do any body have java code or C# code?

Comment: retagged with relevant languages

Comment: Read about multiplication algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm

Comment: "divide and conquer" sounds like homework.  Please retag if correct.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - The "homework" tag is deprecated.

Comment: @HotLicks wasn't three years ago...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Good point.  (I hate zombie threads!)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use [java.math.BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). This allows representations of integer values well in excess of 2^32 or even 2^64. BigInteger values are essentially limited only by the amount of memory available to the program, i.e. ~4 GB on a 32-bit system and pretty much available physical+virutal memory for 64-bit systems.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Foo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BigInteger bigInteger100Fact = bigFactorial(BigInteger("100")); //where bigFactorial is a user-defined function to calculate a factorial
        BigInteger bigIntegerBar = new BigInteger("12390347425734985347537986930458903458");

        BigInteger product = bigIntegerFact.multiply(bigIntegerBar);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's a [BigInteger factorial function](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/numbers/60factorial.html) if you need one

Comment: Just note that BigInteger is using a naive multiplication algorithm so if one needs a FAST multiplication of large numbers, one should use a 3rd party library that uses Karatsuba or another sub n^2 algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's some integer multiplication algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm)

[Here's a class library for numbers](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/)

It includes the Karatsuba and Schonhage-Strassen algorithms for multiplying large integers.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one myself that uses Arrays to accomplish just that, just for fun.  I believe Java's BigInteger class does the same thing though.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx) is an example in C# that might be useful to you.